# Cutter console does not show printf result

Tags: radare2, crackme

I'm using last version (2.0.5) of Cutter. I am not able to find a way to display std in/out in Cutter Console. In the picture I cleared the console before starting debugging and you can see it after the call to the printf. Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks,
L.[image]